# How to Pass all value to another page on blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

How to pass all the value to another razor page if i click the print button?

This is my first page code, im using mudblazor

```
@page "/"
  <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Print" aria-label="print" Class="btn2" Size="Size.Small"
                           Variant="Variant.Outlined" Color="Color.Tertiary" @onclick="(e => Print(context.clear_id))"></MudIconButton>

@code
{
 public async Task Print(int id)
    {
        
        var print = xclearanceList.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.clear_id == id);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/printclearance");

    }
}
```

And this is my 2nd page code

```
@page "/printclearance"
@using GbmsClient.Models

<p>@server.clear_id</p>
<p>@server.name</p>
<p>@server.age</p>
<p>@server.purok</p>
<p>@server.request</p>
<p>@server.date</p>
<p>@server.receipt</p>


@code {
    [Parameter] public clearance server { get; set; } = new clearance();
}
```

I want to pass this all value to my second page .
[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJIr7.png)
[Second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8VcP.png)

Comment: You could use browser storage, a singleton service, pass the class serialized as a parameter or pass the ID and let the second page retrieve the details from the source.

Comment: can you provide me a sample code? im using this code var print = xclearanceList.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.clear_id == id); to pass the id and retrieve the other value but its not working , i think is code is mistaken

Comment: @Brian Parker just gave you a list of techniques to use.  I recommend you google them all and try to write your own code, as you cannot affort to pay his salary. :)

Comment: Or (I assume theses are some form of data items/classes) pass the id of the data to the second page as a parameter and retrieve the data from source in the second page.  There are many tutorials on the internet to show you how to.

Comment: usually the two page can get the same data source use db or server sington, the second page can accept a id argument then you can NavigateTo $"/printclearance?id={id}"

Comment: I mean your second page should have a `xclearanceList` too, and your query `var print = xclearanceList.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.clear_id == id);` should move to second page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all , i solve the problem

```
public async Task Print(int id)
{
    string path = $"printclearance/{id}";
    Nav.NavigateTo(path);
}
```

and this code in my 2nd page

```
[Parameter]
public int id { get; set; }
[Parameter] public clearance server { get; set; } = new clearance();

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    string apiUrl = "https://localhost:7222/api/Clearance/Clearance";
    var response = await Http.GetAsync(apiUrl);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBodyJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var clr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<clearance>>(responseBodyJson);
    server = clr.Where(x => x.clear_id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

on page one you will pass the object values onto a json then store in session. I am assuming your model is called print.
page 1:

```
@code{
 [Inject] ProtectedSessionStorage? _sessionStorage { get; set; }
 JsonSerializerSettings jsonOption = new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, };

 public async Task Print(int id)
 {
     private Print model = new Print();

     var print = xclearanceList.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.clear_id == id);

     model.clear_id = print.clear_id;
     model.name = print.name;
     // etc... for thr rest

     var dataToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
     await _sessionStorage.SetAsync("dataJson", dataToSend);

     NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/printclearance");
 }
}
```

on page two "printclearance" you will recall the session values and put them into al local modem then transfer them to the the main local model.
then clear the session values  Just don't forget to use  "await _sessionStorage.DeleteAsync("dataJson"); " when you logout and on the next page after printclearance page so you clear the session storage var
Page2:

```
@code{
    [Inject] ProtectedSessionStorage? _sessionStorage { get; set; }
private Print model = new Print();


  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRenderer)
    {
        if (firstRenderer == true)
        {
            await GetValuesFromSession();
     
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }


   private async Task GetValuesFromSession(){

 var dataFromSession = await _sessionStorage.GetAsync<string>("dataJson");
        if (dataFromSession.Success == true)
        {
           Print transferModel = new Print();
            transferModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Print>(dataFromSession.Value.ToString());

            model = transferModel; 
        }
}

}
```